# How to get Field Variable on Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, entity, field

I has a issue on my learn project, on case "if condition value is null and then else if condition value field is null" for example my code following these code :

For Entity **Users.java** :

```
@Entity
public class Users {
    private Long id;
    private String employeeId;
    private String fullName;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    ...

    public Users() {
    }

    Some Code Setter and Getter....
}
```

For Entity **Employee.java** :

```
@Entity
public Class Employee {
    private Long id;
    private String employeeId;
    private String fullName;
    ...
    
    public Employee() {
    }
    
    Some Code Setter and Getter....
}
```

and then for my Class Service i have case for insert data Employee with Repository. On case we have validation data before insert data to table Employee, we need to check **table users not null** and then on field **employeeId** should null. with my code following this :

For Repository **UserRepo.java** and **EmployeeRepo.java** :

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepo extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {

}

@Repository
public interdace UsersRepo extends CrudRepository<Users, Long> {

@Transactional
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true, flushAutomatically = true)
@Query("UPDATE Users u SET u.employeeId = :employeeId WHERE u.id = :id")
public void updateEmployeeIdUsers(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("employeeId") String employeeId);

}
```

For Service **UsersService.java** :

```
@Service("usersService")
public class UsersService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UsersRepo repo;
    
    public Optional<Users> findById(Long id) {
        return repo.findById(id);
    }
    
    public void updateEmployeeIdUsers(Long id, String employeeId) {
        repo.updateEmployeeIdUsers(id, employeeId);
    }

}
```

For Service **EmployeeService.java** :

```
@Service("employeeService")
public class EmployeeService {
    
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepo employeeRepo;
    
    @Autowired
    private UsersService userService;
    
    public Employee insertEmployee(Employee employee) throws Exception {
        Optional<Users> users = userService.findById(employee.getId());
        Users userOptional = new Users(); **//on this my problem**
        userOptional.getEmployeeId(); **//on this my problem**
        if (!users.isPresent()) {
            throw new Exception("User ID : "+ employee.getId() +" Not Founded");
        }else if (!(userOptional == null)) { **//on this my problem**
            throw new Exception("User employeID : "+ employee.getEmployeeId() +" Already Exist on Users");
        }
        
        String str1 = "TEST";
        Long idUser = employee.getId();
        userService.updateEmployeeIdUsers(idUser, str1);
        return employeeRepo.save(employee);
    }

}
```

on this code we have problem on else if userOptional is always NULL and i try to debug to see value on employeeId just i see always Null. so any idea with my problem because i try some case alway fail with my issue. please if any idea for my issue, can reply these my question. is very thank you of all about thing to answer my question.

Comment: `userOptional` optional is null because this object is empty. `Users userOptional = new Users();` in this case you just create empty object. I don't understand what is goal of your code.

Comment: Your code will fail always because `(!(userOptional == null))` will be `true` always. You have created a not null instance `Users userOptional = new Users()`

Comment: @Seldo97 yeah that's right, I just found out about it. but how do it works because my goal on this code :
Optional<Users> users = userService.findById(employee.getId());
Should be get value where is it to get employeeId. so how do get this employeId to be include in the else if.

Comment: @doctore how do get this employeId from :
Optional<Users> users = userService.findById(employee.getId()); 
to be include in the else if

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to find a `Users` by `Employee.id` (not an `id` of `Users` instance). If you don't find it => returns an exception. If you find it but `Users.employeeId` is not null => returns an exception `"User employeID : "+ employee.getEmployeeId() +" Already Exist on Users"`. Is this correct?

Comment: So, both entities share the same values for `id` value (if you want to search a `Users.id` using `Employee.id`) and, on the other hand, both ones share `employeeId` values too. If the answer is yes, your current design could has a problem with this "double identifier equality"

Comment: @doctore yes it's true sir, on this case first i need to find user Id and then i need to validate column employeeId it's must be null before i can to update employeeId table users and then insert table employee. so i have same value on column employeId beetwen table users and employee. How do this work for my case sir...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the proposed solution, I will assume the following:

- There is relation between `Employee` and `Users`.
- An `Employee` can be related with only one `Users`
- `username` is the natural key of `Users`
- `employeeId` is the natural key of `Employee`

So the **entities**:

```
@Entity
public class Users {

  @Id
  // This one is an example, you can use the configuration you need
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator= "users_seq")
  @SequenceGenerator(name="users_seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1, sequenceName = "users_id_seq")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "fullname")
  private String fullName;

  // Probably this column should be unique and you need to configure in that way here and in your database
  @Column
  private String username;

  @Column
  private String password;

  // Getter & setter & constructors
}



@Entity
public class Employee {

  @Id
  // This one is an example, you can use the configuration you need
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator= "employee_seq")
  @SequenceGenerator(name="employee_seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1, sequenceName = "employee_id_seq")
  private Long id;

  /**
   * Assuming this is your specific identifier for an employee (not related with database PK)
   *    If the assumption is correct, this column should be unique and you need to configure in
   * that way here and in your database
   */
  @Column(name = "employeeid")
  private String employeeId;

  /**
   * Not sure if this relation could be nullable or not
   */
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "users_id")
  private Users users;

  // Getter & setter & constructors
}
```

As you can see, there are no "repeated columns" in both entities and there is an **unidirectional `OneToOne`** relation between `Employee` and `Users`. If you need a bidirectional one, this link will help you with it: [Bidirectional `OneToOne`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one-bidirectional)

The **repositories**:

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends CrudRepository<Users, Long> {
  Optional<Users> findByUsername(String username);
}



@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {
  Optional<Employee> findByEmployeeId(String employeeId);
}
```

The **services**:

```
@Service
public class UsersService {

  @Autowired
  private UsersRepository repository;

  public Optional<Users> findByUsername(String username) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(username)
            .flatMap(repository::findByUsername);
  }

  public Optional<Users> save(Users user) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(user)
            .map(repository::save);
  }
}



@Service
public class EmployeeService {

  @Autowired
  private EmployeeRepository repository;

  @Autowired
  private UsersService usersService;

  public Optional<Employee> insert(Employee newEmployee) {
    /**
     * The next line don't make sense:
     *
     *   Optional<Users> users = userService.findById(employee.getId());
     *
     * I mean:
     *
     *  1. Usually, id column is configured with @GeneratedValue and manage by database. So you don't need to ask
     *     if that value exists or not in Users.
     *
     *  2. Even if you are including id's values manually in both entities what should be "asked" is:
     *
     *    2.1 Is there any Users in database with the same username than newEmployee.users.username
     *    2.2 Is there any Employee in database with the same employeeId
     *
     *    Both ones, are the natural keys of your entities (and tables in database).
     */
    return Optional.ofNullable(newEmployee)
            .filter(newEmp -> null != newEmp.getUsers())
            .map(newEmp -> {
                isNewEmployeeValid(newEmp);

                // Required because newEmp.getUsers() is a new entity (taking into account the OneToOne relation)
                usersService.save(newEmp.getUsers());

                repository.save(newEmp);
                return newEmp;
            });
  }

  private void isNewEmployeeValid(Employee newEmployee) {
    if (usersService.findByUsername(newEmployee.getUsers().getUsername()).isPresent()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Username: "+ newEmployee.getUsers().getUsername() +" exists in database");
    }
    if (repository.findByEmployeeId(newEmployee.getEmployeeId()).isPresent()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("EmployeeId: "+ newEmployee.getEmployeeId() +" exists in database");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you sir for your example...it's very helpful, and then i can to try do this. i see on your sample used @onetoone which is i within for these is trying it's. but with your sample i can understand with my issue and then i wiss can to clear my issue....thank you very much sir for about this...

Answer (score 1):

After read comments I already understand your problem.

```
Users users = userService.findById(employee.getId()).orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("User ID : "+ employee.getId() +" Not Founded"));
```

And now you can get your `employeeId` from `users` from returned `userService.findById(employee.getId())`;

**Example:**

```
String employeeId = users.getEmployeeId(); // reference to your code
```

But in this case in my opinion you should make relation `@OneToOne` between `users` and `employee` or extend `users` in `employee` class.

[One-To-One relation in JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one),
[hibernate-inheritance](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance)

Comment: Oke Sir i need to try your solution. so i need to changes my Entitiy class to employeId becomes relation '@OneToOne between table users and employee. wich is my current design is false because i haven't apply design '@OneToOne or extend users in employee class....thank you sir for answer my question.....i will to update after i to try your solution sir.
I hope this solution provides the answer I was looking for

Comment: And you don't need update query. `save()` work like update too.